# How to capitalize a Moment component in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I have the following component:

```
<Moment element={Text}
        format="MMM DD, YYYY \at h:mma"
        style={dateStyle}
>
    {this.props.updateDate}
</Moment>
```

It's currently ouputting something like `Jan 01, 2017 at 12:53pm`, but I need it to output `JAN 01, 2017 AT 12:53PM` instead.

Normally you would use `{string.toUppercase()}` to achieve this, but I'm having issues figuring out how to get at the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `UpperText` component and pass that to `Moment` as `element`.  In your `UpperText` component, apply `toUppercase()` to its string child and return `Text` with the uppercase text.

Answer (score 5):

At the time I responded initially in 2017, I was wrong to suggest that one could simply use the CSS `text-transform: uppercase`. React-Native doesn't use traditional CSS, but [uses JavaScript to add styles](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style).

At the time, this was not supported by React-Native. I should have deleted the answer.

However, since then, the `Text` Component `style` property now supports:

```
textTransform: 'uppercase'
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#style

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working in React-Native where the options for CSS styles are much more limited. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize how limited it was.